# Using ISNULL in where clause

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @use10percent INT

SELECT 
    @use10percent = COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    [dbo].[CUSTOMER_ORDER] o
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[CUSTOMER] c ON c.ID = o.CUSTOMER_ID
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[CUST_ADDRESS] ca ON ca.CUSTOMER_ID = o.CUSTOMER_ID 
                            AND ca.ADDR_NO = o.[SHIP_TO_ADDR_NO]
WHERE 
    o.[ID] = @CUST_ORDER_ID
    AND (isnull(ca.STATE, c.STATE) IN ('AB','BC','MB','MT','NB','NS','ON','PQ','QC','SK','TX','NY'))

/**/
UPDATE SHIPPER_LINE
SET ACT_FREIGHT = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2),
                     (CASE
                         WHEN CAST(ShipWeight AS Float) >= 400 
                           THEN CAST(Rate AS Float) * 1.06
                         WHEN CAST(ShipWeight AS Float) < 400 
                           THEN CASE
                                    WHEN @use10percent = 0 
                                      THEN CAST(Rate AS Float) * 1.20
                                    ELSE CAST(Rate AS Float) * 1.10 --New rate for Canada, TX, and NY
                                END
                         ELSE CAST(Rate AS Float)
                       END))
```

The goal of this trigger is to add 10% to the freight charge when the weight is under 400lbs and the destination state is NY, TX, or all of Canada. It works if the customer uses a drop ship address (ca.state) and I get a 10% increase. But if the customer is the buyer and destination, the (ca.state) is null and the (c.state) needs to be used. The code above adds the full 20% if the (ca.state) is null and the (c.state) is NY, TX, or Canada.

How can I fix the where clause to filter correctly?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I get the where clause to use the c.state when the ca.state is null? The code above gives a 20% increase when the c.state is NY, when I want it to only increase by 10%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WHERE part about STATE check seems to be good:
isnull(ca.STATE, c.STATE) IN ('AB','BC','MB','MT','NB','NS','ON','PQ','QC','SK','TX','NY')
If it adds 20% it means that @use10percent is zero, are you sure about JOIN and data into the tables? Have you attempted removing COUNT and watching about SELECT result?

Comment: Upon trying the select statement by itself I discovered that it was excluding the correct results. Changing the cust_address join from an inner join to a left join solved the issue. The trigger works correctly now.